# Standardizing TreeView and ListView Image Calls from Resources

Tags: vb.net, image, treeview

In Form1.Load, I am setting the following TreeView1 images from Resources as follows:

```
TreeView1ImageList.Images.Add("table", My.Resources.table)
TreeView1ImageList.Images.Add("excel", My.Resources.excel)
TreeView1ImageList.Images.Add("access", My.Resources.access)
TreeView1.ImageList = TreeView1ImageList
```

However, when I load list boxes in UserControls, I am using (e.g.):

```
ListView1.SmallImageList = Form1.ImageList1
If datatype = 1 Then ListView1.ImageIndex = 0
If datatype = 2 Then ListView1.ImageIndex = 1
If datatype = 3 Then ListView1.ImageIndex = 2
If datatype = 4 Then ListView1.ImageIndex = 3
```

Regarding the e.g. image calls such as "ListView1.ImageIndex = 0", is there a way to use an image name like "table" or "excel" from Resources instead of an image index?

It would be better to use Resources for all image sources and get away from imageindex etc.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly then you should be setting the `ImageKey` rather than `ImageIndex`.  That said, assuming that `datatype` will always have one of those values, that second code snippet could be replaced with this:

```
ListView1.ImageIndex = datatype + 1
```